# Mysql optimization with key definition

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have following table. I don't know whether defining of additional keys should cause reduction in server speed or not?
In other words, if I define 10 or more keys to any MySQL table, will my query speed be raised or not? Also, is it recommended (adding more keys to table)?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xxx` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`intval1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval8` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval9` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval10` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval11` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval12` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval13` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval14` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval15` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval16` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval17` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval18` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval19` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`intval20` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: Without context, doesn't help you could have a single table with 100+ columns... but if the relationship to the database and other correlated tables (such as lookup tables), you could be shooting yourself in the foot right away... Look into Data Normalization Guildelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any index you add will slow down inserts and updates of values in the indexed columns because the index(es) will need to be updated. (This might be offset by speed-up on updates that use a WHERE clause.)

Otherwise, the only way to answer your question is to know what queries will be issued against the table. If a query will require MySQL to look up rows by value of `id` and/or `intval1`, then an index on `intval2` won't speed up anything.

Generally, you should only index columns that help with your queries. For further information, check out the MySQL manual section on [Optimization and Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Proper indexing depends on the queries used (otherwise it would be just automatic), and size of indexes and their count matters. They slow down writting (insert, update) but accelerate selecting (select, update, delete - as they are used to resolve the where clause for update/delete).

Keep in mind, that you can have 1 index on many columns, but it can be used only if the left-most columns in the index are used in the query. As MySQL uses only 1 index to resolve the query (not technically true if there is join conditions, but for simple queries), in many cases compound index is better. (recent version of MySQL support index_merge with more than 1 index used to resolve the query, but still it's slower than a compound index).

If the storage engine is InnoDB, and all the columns you are selecting only columns which are part of the index used, the query is the really fast (it's known as index-covered query)

Also, important think when you decide if you have to use index or not for a particular column is the index selectivity - the average number of records per unique value in the index. If you have 100 000 records but only 2 possible values and near 50%:50% distribution, the selectivity will be low - MySQL still will have to scan near 50 000 records. If there are 10 000 distinct values, selectivity is high and this is a good index.

Having multiple indexes that can be used in the same query can lead to a situation where MySQL is not chosing the best one.

In 1 sentence: keep count of indexes as lower as you can (but have index for each query executed, except if you know table-scan is a better choice in your situation) and prefer compound indexes instead of separate indexes on different columns.